# InstallShield 2012 - Deploying app with Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable?

Tags: .net, wpf, deployment, installshield, redistributable

I'm using InstallShield 2012 to deploy wpf app,

I want to integrate both .Net Framework 4.5 Full Package and  Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable into single setup file.

I did follow the guide http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/

But after using this setup file to install on client machine (not installed .Net 4.5 and not installed Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable too). The result is the setup wizard asked for installing .Net Framework 4.5 first (it's fine), but I don't see it asked for installing Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable.

I have searched much, but so far I can't solve yet.

Someone can tell me how to fix this issue?

Many Thanks,

T&T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to the operatingsystemconditions configuration in the Installshield pre-requisite file Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package (x86).prq located in the Installshield SetupPrerequisites directory.

The operatingsystemconditions section specifies which versions of Windows, including service packs, 32/64 bits, the redistributable file should be installed on.

To resolve this I copied the operatingsystemconditions section from the Visual C++ 2010 prq file into the 2012 prq file.

See http://daniellang.net/installshield-and-microsoft-visual-c-2010-redistributables/ for some more details.

Comment: Installshield 2012 Spring LE edition has still this issue. Had to modify the conditions by hand as the LE does not have any editor for that. I must admit that the Spring LE edition is worse than nothing.